# Issue with Logitech Gaming Software macro scripting

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I tried to write a script that's just drag your mouse down when right and left mouse button is clicked. Basically it's like norecoil script for shooting game.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
    EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2 and IsKeyLockOn"capslock" then
    OutputLogMessage("RMB Pressed")
    repeat
        if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
            OutputLogMessage("LMB Pressed")
            repeat
                Sleep(16)
                MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
                Sleep(16)
                MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
                Sleep(16)
                MoveMouseRelative(0, 2)
                Sleep(16)
                MoveMouseRelative(1, 1)
                Sleep(16)
                MoveMouseRelative(0, -1)
                Sleep(16)
                MoveMouseRelative(0, 1)
                Sleep(16)
                MoveMouseRelative(-2, 2)
            until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
                OutputLogMessage("LMB Released")
        end
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
        OutputLogMessage("RMB Released")
end
```

With this code i'm getting OutputLogMessage in script editor but there is no mouse movement at all. I'm kind confused where i could make a mistake?

Comment: `arg==3` means "middle mouse button".  Try `arg==2` for RMB.  Please note that `IsMouseButtonPressed(3)` is correct - here 3 means RMB (and 2 MMB). I'm not joking :-)

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't work, whenever i press mouse button it only moves by one pixel , but while i'm on desktop it works normal.

Comment: Your script triggers when you press RMB while keeping LMB pressed.  Is it not what you want?  Please describe what means "it still doesn't work".

Comment: Yes.  It looks like script does only one time MoveMouseRelative and then just stops, it doesn't go through whole code it waits for another mouse click.

Comment: It is unclear where the code stops.  Please insert "debug checkpoints" inside your code `OutputLogMessage("Checkpoint 1")` to understand exact code behavior.  Does the code stops on the first or the second `until` statement?

Comment: I updated original post.

Comment: How many times the inner repeat-until loop executes until exiting?  You can get the count by inserting `OutputLogMessage` inside the loop.  How long do you keep LMB pressed?

Comment: It seems that issue was with Logitech Gaming Software, i uninstalled it and installed Logitech G HUB and now it works perfect. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Here, use this one. Feel free to customize it based on your needs:

```
 local Activate = 3     -- Wheel button to activate/deactivate local
 recoil = false -- Disable/Enable script
 EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);   function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == Activate) then
        recoil = not recoil         if (recoil == false) then
          OutputLogMessage("OFF-NoRecoil\n")
          OutputLCDMessage("OFF-NoRecoil")          else
          OutputLogMessage("ON-NoRecoil\n")
          OutputLCDMessage("ON-NoRecoil")       end     end     if recoil then      antiRecoil();   end end function antiRecoil()       repeat      -- if mouse1
 pressed then       MoveMouseRelative(0,5)      Sleep(17)                   until not
 IsMouseButtonPressed(1)     end
```

Comment: The formatting of your code (i.e. the misuse of line-breaks and indentation) is *terrible*. Please consider editing it to make it more readable.